# Exclude current post for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

What I need: show random post except current post for custom post type `Question`

In below codes, the exclusion doesn't works. It simply show any post including current post.

```
<?php
    $my_query = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => '8', 'post_type' => 'question', 'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ), 'orderby' => 'rand'));
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title() ?></a><br>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If I change the `Question` to be `Page`, it works for Page. If remove the `Question`, it works for Post.

I guess it must be something I missed if I want to make it works for custom post type

**Update:**

Previously I wrote `Question` now changed to `question`, but still results the same

Comment: Post type names should be a maximum of 20 characters and they **cannot contain capital letters** or spaces. So `Question` should probably be `question`

Comment: As Dave mentioned, post_type cannot have capital letters, it's the slug of the post type. "post" is the default value for that parameter (hence when you don't use it, it takes posts by default). the rest of the query is correct, however do check if $post->ID is actually returning the ID you need.

Comment: Changed `Question` to `question` also results same.

Comment: `$post->ID` however giving wrong number to custom post type but works fine on Post & Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `get_queried_object()` or `get_queried_object_id()` to get the current custom post's ID. IMO `get_queried_object()` is a better choice here as you can conditionaly check for the post type also. Try this

```
function wpse258217_random_posts() {

    $obj = get_queried_object();

    if ( $obj->post_type === 'question' ) {
        $postid = $obj->ID;

        $my_query = new WP_Query( array('showposts' => '8', 'post_type' => 'question', 'post__not_in' => array( $postid ), 'orderby' => 'rand'));

        //Execute the loop here
    }

}
```